# How to display Google Calendar events on multiple lines?

Tags: google-calendar

I would like to use more the vertical space of my screen when looking at Google Calendar and I would like to be able to display an event on multiple lines if its title is longer than cell width.

Here it is an example of current situation:

[image]

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure it's not possible from within Google Calendar itself. Google never gives you many possibilities in editing their interfaces.

What would be possible to to make a CSS user script and edit the design by hand.

Try this Chrome Extension: [Minimalist for Google Calendar™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgljgiacemcbnibkkmbolnljeffaadna)

It adds a number of options to modify the interface of Google Calendar. It also has a method for inserting custom CSS. Although I think editing Google's CSS code would be quite hard, if you're a little experienced with you can give it a try, I think you will figure out soon enough weither or not you have a chance to succeed.

Comment: Link is not working.